# How do I get information about a git repo using absolute paths

Tags: git, svn

I'm writing some scripts to get info about the git repositories that I've got set up locally. This is best explained using a simple example:

```
machine:~ anon$ mkdir test
machine:~ anon$ cd test
machine:test anon$ mkdir myrepo
machine:test anon$ cd myrepo/
machine:myrepo anon$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/anon/test/myrepo/.git/
machine:myrepo anon$ echo this is a test >> test.txt
machine:myrepo anon$ git add test.txt 
machine:myrepo anon$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) d9b8bf0] first commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
machine:myrepo anon$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
machine:myrepo anon$ git log
commit d9b8bf02d5ff8b214d3ac44308c53ee6c8bcaac5
Author: Anon Ymus <anon@website.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 3 13:22:17 2014 +0000

    first commit
machine:myrepo anon$ cd ~
machine:~ anon$ git status ${HOME}/test/myrepo/
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I can only get info about my repo if the working directory is in a git repo.

I could modify my scripts to change the working directories to the git repo then back. But I would prefer to avoid this if possible because my scripts are intended to work both for SVN and for GIT. For example, with SVN commands like:

```
svn info /this/is/a/fullpath
```

work fine no matter what the path or working directory is, so I would prefer a solution that maps as closely to this as possible for the sake of consistency.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git --git-dir=the/local/repo/.git --work-tree=the/local/repo status
```

[Git Status From Outside of the Working Directory](http://bubblefoundry.com/blog/2011/02/git-status-from-outside-of-the-working-directory)